# Press and hold to make Image move

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have a button and an image. When the button is pressed and held I want the image to movie across the screen quickly. Right now after I press and hold it just moves after I let go. I need it to start moving after a certain amount of time and stop when I let go. 
here is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonDown:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    x = x + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below code, you have to push 3 seconds to move _imageView, and then the image begins moving, and when you release the button, the image stops.

[image: ss]

```
- (IBAction)pushToMove:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(move) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}

- (void)move
{
    _nt = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(goRight)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
}

- (void)goRight
{
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x + 10, _imageView.frame.origin.y,
                                  _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
}

- (IBAction)stop
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(move) object:nil];
    [_nt invalidate];
}
```

I put this sample project to GitHub. You can download and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120804_ImageMoveDuringPushButton

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in interface builder by simply liking to the buttons touch down property instead of touch up inside. In code it looks like this:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In addition to this, you'll want to do some state checking on your animation, and use `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` as an option to help it pick up where it left off when the user presses the button again.

Comment: I have the "[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];" already in but still nothing happens until I take my finger off the button. I need it to happen while my finger is on. Does that make sense?